# Codeigniter .htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I don't understand how can this work and the later doesn't... If I have a .htaccess on my `root`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

and my index in `root/public/index.php` everything works fine when I enter my URL (localhost). Page redirects finds my index and deletes a part of URL.

But if I relocate everything in another file `root/en` and throw .htaccess file in there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !en/public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ en/public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

it just doesn't want to redirect me to `root/en/public/index.php` anymore when I type localhost/en... I get "The page you requested was not found."

Comment: If you remove the .htaccess file and attempt to browse to the directory via the full path does codeigniter load or do you get the same error? (http://localhost/en/public)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting **RewriteBase** to the directory you put your application

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteBase /en
```

Comment: I get Internal Server Error which means my .htaccess is wrong with the current setup